# Spam in the VS2010 Extension Manager

Tags: visual-studio-2010

What's with all the spam (free trials and so on from Component One & Telerik among others) in the VS 2010 Extensions Manager. Without going to the website there is no way to know whether a listing is free or trialware so, for me, the entire user experience of the Extensions Manager is ruined.

Anyone else finding this? Is there a way of suppressing these?

Alex...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that helps slightly is to browse Tools specifically.  I tried adding things like `-trial` or `-componentone`, but it seems that the extension manager/gallery ignores the `-`.  I'll send an email to some people to see if that can be fixed.

Answer (score -1):

If you go to the visual studio gallery web page, ( http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ ), on the left you can click on Categories, versions, and so forth that will filter out usless addin's.

For instance, I filter on VS 2010, and Free. This takes out paid, and Free Trial, such as the jerks at ComponentOne and Telerik.

Try: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=CostCategory&f%5B0%5D.Value=0&f%5B0%5D.Text=Free&f%5B1%5D.Type=VisualStudioVersion&f%5B1%5D.Value=10.0&f%5B1%5D.Text=Visual%20Studio%202010

Comment: I think his question was specifically about the extension manager, not the gallery ("Without going to the website...the entire user experience of the Extensions Manager is ruined.").

Comment: As Noah said, this is the gallery, I'm specifically talking about the Extension Manager.

Comment: Your correct. Sorry, I guess I never really looked at the extension manager. I always went directly to the web site.